# Performance tuning of application

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, websphere-8, message-driven-bean

Performance of my application reduces drastically under high load. This is message driven bean based restful api. For average load of 27 hits per second I had configured maximum server sessions as 20 in both nodes of websphere application server, kept Queue Connection factory session pool to 20 and JDBC connection pool to 20. With these setting average load performance test went fine and I was able to get response in 1 second with no time outs.

But under peak load which is 3 times average load i.e 80 hits per second, the application performs poorly with more than half the requests getting timed out and average response time going as high as 6 seconds.

For peak load maximum server session were raised to 40 for each node, Queue Connection factory session pool to 40 and JDBC connection pool to 40. On monitoring through HP Diagnostics, I could find that Database Server's CPU utilization went very high, i.e upto 98%.

My question is does having more number of connections to database increases cpu utilization rapidly or is it more dependent on the queries being fired. Also is it possible to reduce the number connections in JDBC Connection pool or there should be one connection per MDB Instance

Please provide ways in which I can improve the performance under peak load.

Comment: This has a lot of variables in play here. You should always use pool connections as the cost of creating a connection on demand is expensive in most cases. I would recommend profiling the application and first finding where your application may have long processing time. Some thoughts about the external DB is that as a whole your DB should have a specific throughput of X which depends on the DB software, the CPU available, the disk IO and if not on same machine network IO. Your application may be fine and its the DB throughput. You may or may not have to throttle the application to the DB.

Comment: If you have performance tests, why don't you just try it with the peak load and see how different settings affect the throughput?

Comment: @Kayaman I did not get your point. Which settings are you referring to?

Comment: @Underbalanced How can I find out what throughput can the DB support?

Comment: @Neel Any settings you feel like tinkering with.

Comment: @Neel Should be able to use a stand alone application or the build in DB tools to see or measure performance. You probably would want to run the test from another machine. What is the database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

To your specific questions, strictly speaking, having more connections to the DB will likely not significantly increase the DB server CPU utilization by itself.  Memory footprint, somewhat, CPU util, not so much.  It is only when those connections are used by the application that the SQL which is executed on those connections drives up the CPU utilization.  It is possible to reduce the connection pool size to less than the number of MDB's but in general that's not a good idea.  You can tune performance by a number of means, one way is simply by measuring CPU utilization of the DB server.  Start by determining what is a typical and a high transaction load created by your application on a single connection.  Driving your application to generate the typical load, increase the number of paths (connections and MDB instances) until you drive the DB server CPU at 50%.  Now, drive the application at the highest expected transaction rate.  Make certain the DB server CPU utilization remains at a comfortable level you pick, perhaps 80%.  If it is less than 80%, try adding connections/MDB instances until it does.  If it is greater than 80%, reduce the number of connections and MDB instances until it approaches 80%.  This is only one of many ways to tune performance and of course relies on the fact that you have the ability to generate load on your application at a predictable rate.

Comment: On further analysis I could find out that the CPU utilization is going very high in Database server, almost 98% and that is when the timeouts starts happening. Checking other forums i could find that the run queue count found after running vmstat should not be more than the cpus on the server. I could see that the run count is going as high as 70 whereas no of cpus is only 16. Now what can be done here, is it like the hardware just cannot support this much throughput and additional cpus are required or something else can be done here.